# GNU Guile Scheme on Windows

Tags: windows, scheme, lisp, gnu, guile

I want to install the gnu guile scheme on Windows.

However, I am lost. There isn't a clear guide on how to do that. Most of the methods I found are for macOS, FreeBSD and Linux-based OS which in all of them is a simple command.

Help!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can use Cygwin or Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) to create a Unix-like environment on your Windows system, and after this try running it in this environment

Comment: Warning. You will be a niche user-group of an already niche project. Be prepared to do a lot of learning and don't expect a lot of people to be able to help. I would definitely join the mailing list and chat channels if I were you.

Comment: @RichardHuxton in the end using WSL was the easiest option. As you mentioned there are barely any docs for windows even while looking on github.